# Xcode - Two targets with same bundle version

Tags: xcode, version, bundle

I have two targets configured for my app, one for debug/beta stages, and another for release.
Since I want them to have different display names, each one has its own Info.plist file.
However, I'd like that both had always the same bundle version number automatically, so I could increase just one, and the other automatically follows the first. Is this possible?